# Vertical line in android layout passing through Views

Tags: android, xml

How can I add a line in my layout connecting the Views as shown below?

[image: https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/3b/ec/d2/3becd28fa9f9332f390d88da445e2bc7.jpg]

Comment: Simply have the line as part of yout background or draw it on canvas. Then use some colored or grey drawable for the bullets (possibly, as **compound drawables**) - OR draw them on canvas as well.

Comment: I would rather recommend to have part of the line in each row of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in lot of ways. Just try this below way.You can apply the images below the lines. You can also set the marginLeft,marginRight and other adjustments based on your need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/AntiqueWhite">
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="65dp">
<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:background="@color/Black"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp">
    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:background="@color/Black"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp">
    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:background="@color/Black"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why do you need all those nested RelativeLayouts?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Single RelativeLayout is also enough

Comment: Not "also enough". It's enough. Layout nesting is bad for performances.